# How to parse XAML string to use it in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to have string containing `Inline` markups like

```
var str = "foo bar <Bold>dong</Bold>"
```

and feed TextBlock with it so the text would get formatted like it would be added to Inlines collection. How could I achive that?

Comment: do you want to see it as plain text ?

Comment: I would like to see it rendered as formatted text

Comment: consider using rich text box and format accordingly !

Comment: richtextbox is editable and making it disabled doesn't make it look like TextBlock :)

Comment: downvoters dare to justify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the text with a `<TextBlock>` tag and parse the whole thing as XAML:

```
public TextBlock CreateTextBlock(string inlines)
{
    var xaml = "<TextBlock xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">"
        + inlines + "</TextBlock>";
    return XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as TextBlock;
}
```

Then use the newly created TextBlock as you like. Put it in some Panel

```
var str = "foo bar <Bold>dong</Bold>";
grid.Children.Add(CreateTextBlock(str));
```

or perhaps copy its `Inlines` to another TextBlock.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below code.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock"/>

 string regexStr = @"<S>(?<Str>.*?)</S>|<B>(?<Bold>.*?)</B>";
        var str = "<S>foo bar </S><B>dong</B>";
        Regex regx = new Regex(regexStr);
        Match match = regx.Match(str);
        Run inline = null;
        while (match.Success)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Str"].Value))
            {
                inline = new Run(match.Groups["Str"].Value);
                txtBlock.Inlines.Add(inline);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Bold"].Value))
            {
                inline = new Run(match.Groups["Bold"].Value);
                inline.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                txtBlock.Inlines.Add(inline);
            }
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
```